# How can you implement a rails checkout button that leads to a modal for entering credit card info?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, braintree, materialize

I am using rails, materializeCss modal and braintree 'dropin' to process my forms. I embedded the braintree "dropin" in a div in the form that has a modal class. When you click the checkout button it opens the div with the 'dropin' and form submit button. However the modal div is hidden behind the dark overlay when the checkout button is clicked.

```
<%= form_for([@listing, @listing.order.new]) do |f| %>
    //lots of code

    <!-- modal trigger start  --> 

    <button class="modal-trigger btn btn-large waves-effect cyan waves-light" id="book" data-target="modal1">Proceed to Checkout</button>

    <!-- modal trigger end --> 

    <!-- modal start  --> 

    <div class="modal " id="modal1" >
        <div class="modal-content">
            <h4 id="credit-text center-align">Enter your Credit card details </h4>
            <div id="dropin"></div>

            <button class="btn btn-large center-align" type="submit" name="action">Request Booking</button>

        </div>                        
    </div>
    <!-- modal end  -->
<% end %>

//added an alert just to make sure the modal is firing.
<script>
    $(function(){
       $('.modal-trigger').leanModal({  ready: function() { alert('Ready'); }});
   });
</script>
```

I think the fact that the modal div is inside the form may have something to do with it but the forms submit button is inside the modal so I cant put the modal outside the form. How can fix this ? Is there a better way of implementing a modal checkout ?

Answer (score 0):

You might be overwriting `z-index` CSS rules while styling your modal.

Make sure that your `.modal` has higher `z-index` than the overlaying dark background.